# getting warning messages "avahi-daemon[3201]: Invalid query packet." on suse 10.1 server with raid 1

Tags: opensuse, avahi

I had recently replaced a failing hard drive on my software raid 1 system with suse 10.1 , and i am checking for any warning messages on  " var/log/warn " and i found this message

"avahi-daemon[3201]: Invalid query packet."

more than 12 times , i am new to these stuff , should i be concerned , is there something wrong with the system , can i check anywhere else to find out if there is any problem with the system.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

These error messages are completely harmless, they were caused by upgrades to the Mac OS X Bonjour service, transmitting packets it previously did not that the Avahi code currently considers invalid.

They won't cause any problems and can be safely ignored.